# CreateObject -- Where did the Object come from

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In the code below

```
Dim s As Object = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
```

How does my application figure out what a *Notes.NotesSession* is and instantiate it? I'd like to add a reference to my application so I can write something more like

```
Dim s As Notes.NotesSession = New Notes.NotesSession
```

But I can't figure out where this *Notes.NotesSession* is coming from. The computer can find it, why can't I?

---

### EDIT

For COM references I have

- Lotus Domino Objects -- Interop.Domino.dll
- Lotus Notes Automation Classes -- Interop.lotus.dll

Domino.NotesSession casts to a progID "Lotus.NotesSession.7.0" object but not a progID "Notes.NotesSession", which is the object whose reference I am trying to find.

Lotus.NotesSession can't instantiate at all as it is an interface?

Looking to add a design time reference to the "Notes.NotesSession" object, but in the registry HKLM it gives a path of *C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\notes.exe/Automation*  which I don't understand.

Comment: It comes from the registry (in HKCR).  Learn about COM registration.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find an entry called Notes.NotesSession in HKCR  :)

Comment: Project > Add Reference > COM tab.  Search for something resembling "IBM" or "Notes", maybe "Lotus".

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the references I could find and detailed them above.